# Setting up ISC-DHCP server getting DHCPDISCOVER, DHCPOFFER constantly

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, bind, isc-dhcp

Working on trying to setup a new server to run [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/) on. I have setup the server to serve DHCP addresses only on eth1 and not eth0. I have installed isc-dhcp and bind9 on the server.

I cannot get a client to be assigned a DHCP address. In the /var/log/syslog file I get the following repeating over and over:

```
Sep 14 08:10:03 fog dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from (mac address here) (N049) via eth1
Sep 14 08:10:03 fog dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.10.20 to (mac address here) (N049) via eth1
Sep 14 08:10:19 fog dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from (mac address here) (N049) via eth1
Sep 14 08:10:19 fog dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.10.20 to (mac address here) (N049) via eth1
```

My /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf file looks like this:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
ddns-domainname "chcfog.local";
ddns-rev-domainname "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa";

#include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "my key here";
};

zone theapartment.lan. {
primary 127.0.0.1;
key "rndc-key";
}

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "chcfog.local";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.11, 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;
#option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;

#default-lease-time 600;
#max-lease-time 7200;
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;

authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.150;
        zone 10.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
                primary 192.168.10.1;
                key "rndc-key";
        }
}
```

My /etc/bind/named.conf.local:

```
key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "my key here";
};

zone "chcfog.local" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/chcfog.local.hosts";
        allow-update { key rndc-key; };
};

zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/10.168.192.rev";
        allow-update { key rndc-key; };
};
```

My 10.168.192.rev file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
10.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN SOA  ns.chcfog.local. email.address.here. (
                            1263187366 ; serial
                            10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                            3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                            604800     ; expire (1 week)
                            38400      ; minimum (10 hours 40 minutes)
                            )
    NS      ns.chcfog.local.
1 PTR ns.chcfog.local.
```

My chcfog.local.hosts file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day

chcfog.local IN SOA  ns.chcfog.local. dkassner.centerforhospice.org. (
          1263527838 ; serial
          10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
          3600       ; retry (1 hour)
          604800     ; expire (1 week)
          38400      ; minimum (10 hours 40 minutes)
          )

    NS  ns.chcfog.local.
    A   192.168.10.1

ns.chcfog.local A       192.168.10.1
ns              A       192.168.10.1
```

eht1 section of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.10.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

Any ideas why this DHCP server would not work?

Answer (score 2):

The DHCP server does work (it sends `DHCPOFFER` in response to the client's `DHCPDISCOVER`). However, the server never receives a `DHCPREQUEST` from the client to actually request the offered address.

Run `tcpdump -n udp port 68` or `dhcpdump -i INTERFACE` on both the server and the client and then run `dhclient -1` on the client. The dump on both sides should reveal whether the client doesn't receive the `DHCPOFFER` from the server, or the server doesn't receive the `DHCPREQUEST` from the client.